# Google App Engine interactive console using the Terminal

Tags: google-app-engine, console, interactive

Following instructions on this page, [Accessing the datastore remotely with remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html):

I edited `app.yaml` to include these lines:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

I opened up a Terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/app
$ python2.5 /usr/local/google_appengine/remote_api.shell.py\
            -s localhost:8082 -p /_ah/remote_api
```

At the root of my app folder structure, I have a module named `foobar.py`, as well as a package named `data_models`. After gaining access to the `remote_api` Python interpreter, I try the following lines:

```
import foobar
import data_models
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foobar

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named data_models
```

How do I access the interactive console through the Terminal? Am I missing something? The same thing happens even if I login to the cloud server:

```
$ python2.5 /usr/local/google_appengine/remote_api.shell.py\
            -s my-app.appspot.com -p /_ah/remote_api
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remote_api` just makes it possible to make RPC calls from a local task to a remote instance of an App Engine app. The Python console itself is still local, and everything you do executes locally. That means that any modules you try and import must exist on your local machine, somewhere your Python instance can find them - probably by adding your app's directory to `PYTHONPATH`, like this:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/my/app/dir python2.5 /usr/local/google_appengine/remote_api.shell.py\
        -s my-app.appspot.com -p /_ah/remote_api
```

Comment: I haven't tried out your solution yet, but, just a comment: Isn't the fact that I ran `python2.5` from `/my/app/dir` (or `/path/to/app` in my example) already means that Python will search that folder first?

Comment: @Kit No - Python's PYTHONPATH does not include the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines to my `.bash_profile` so that I won't have to edit `PYTHONPATH` every time I fire up the Terminal.

```
PYTHONPATH = "/path/to/app"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the remote_api is in a different path than your app so it curpwd is that of the remote_api so your app's code is not available